# Draco (gltf 2.0) texture appears rotated after importing from Blender

Tags: three.js, textures, blender, gltf

As it is well known, threejs.org recommends using gltf for models.

I'm trying to use a simple shape (plane) with a texture.
When I export from Blender 2.97b the shape appears 180 degrees rotated so I rotate the shape in Blender to avoid rotating it in three.js.
The real problem is that the texture always appears rotated vs the mesh, no matter what I tried. Has anyone imported gltf from Blender? I wonder if anything will ever work properly when using Blender...

Blender export settings I use for gltf 2.0:

- export selected only
- convert z-up to y-up
- export texture coordinates
- export normals
- export materials

I have installed pipeline via node.js and each time I convert and compress to .glb based on the Khronos info here:[enter link description here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/tree/master/scripts)

I also use a Three.MeshBasicMaterial and assign the png image as a map.

Comment: Note the section on Textures in the docs here: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader

Comment: @Don McCurdy That was it, thanks, 'texture.flipY' is needed when texture is added externally.  I expected the same behavior as with my other models that used embedded textures, my bad, but such inconsistencies (in all software) make us waste many hours or days -as in my case. When there is no need to change the texture, the ideal solution is to use embedded textures and then reference them to a three.js material for control, which is what I finally did a single .glb file and no need for 'texture.flipY'. That should be mentioned in the documentation IMO.

Comment: If you’d like to suggest an improvement to the docs, PRs are welcome. The section above is what is there so far. :)